# VueSocket - Emit a message to all open app instances

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to broadcast a message to two browsers running the same app using Vue-socket.

When the app is created, I hook a listener for new messages to it like so:

```
mounted: function(){
this.$socket.on('newMessage ', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  })
}
```

When I type a message in one browser, it's sent to the server and received in the event below. I can `console.log` it.

```
socket:{
    events:{
    receivedMsg: function(data){
      this.$socket.emit('newMessage', data)
      this.$store.dispatch('socket_updateMsg', data)
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `emit` event doesn't seem to trigger the listener yet my app has a `VueSocketIO` attached to it.

```
Vue.use(VueSocketIO, 'http://localhost:3001')

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was on my backend server.

I was using

```
socket.emit('receivedMsg', postedMessage);
```

Which I changed to

```
io.sockets.emit('receivedMsg', postedMessage);
```

And now all browsers can see the message.